# How do I loop a certain portion of my code?

Tags: c#

I need to loop a portion of my application. Let's call this a. There is a part of my app that loops regardless, b. I only want portion a to loop, but not b. Is there any way at all that I can do this?

Here's a concrete example. This is the console command.

```
Console.Write("Command> ");
string cmd = Console.ReadLine();
```

I found a way to do this by putting `return;` after every Command, but it is slow and ineffective.

Is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: A illustrative sample of code would really help here.

Comment: Please provide some code and more description.Your question seems vague.

Comment: Are loops `a` and `b` nested loops meaning loop within a loop or separate ones?

Comment: No, it doesn't, Fletcher.

Comment: Unfortunately, that edit invalidated thaGH05T's answer. I've merged your two questions. I still don't quite get what you're after, but were you able to understand and try that answer's suggestions?

Comment: So, I have some commands: `if (cmd == "help") { //print the help file on screen; return; }` This Method is slow. i have seen a case where the author uses: `public static void command() { Console.Write("XCube $>"); string input = Console.ReadLine(); return; }` but i don't understand how that method works, as I can't see where the `return;` command returns to. Hope this clarifies things.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit obvious but remove the b section of the code from the loop. Also set an escape variable and when the condition is met the loop will exit cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in a form and you want a timer or a method to check process, etc. you can add this at your program load:

```
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
//Initialize your stuff
_loop();

}

private void _loop()
{
while(true)
{
try { //Stuff you want to loop } 
catch { //If sometimes goes wrong??? }
}
}
```

Now you can do anything you want in your program, and the loop will keep running
I have done this yeah, but I don't recommend it, it makes the program kind of laggy depending on what are you looping.